# Django — Can't get static CSS files to load

Tags: python, css, django

What im trying to link in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}"/>
```

and I have also done {%load static%}

my file structure is like this:

```
signup/static/assets/css/main.css
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'signup/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

the error:

```
[29/Feb/2020 17:19:31] "POST /postsign/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3445
Not Found: /postsign/signup/static/assets/css/main.css
```

I cant understand where that /postsign/ is coming from

my urls.py is like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.signIn),
    path('postsign/', views.postsign),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name="log"),
    path('signup/', views.signUp, name="signup"),
    path('postsignup/', views.postsignup, name="postsignup"),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name="prof"),
]
```

and the postsign method is:

```
def postsign(request):
    email = request.POST.get('Email')
    passw = request.POST.get("Password")
    try:
        user = authe.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, passw)
    except:
        message = "Invalid Username or Password"
        return render(request, "signin.html", {"messg": message})
    print(user['idToken'])
    session_id = user['idToken']
    request.session['uid'] = str(session_id)
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

Django ver 3.0.3 if that helps

Comment: Where is your signup/static/ located in?

Comment: what django version u use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add leading slash to `STATIC_URL` to avoid the static URLs from being relative:

```
STATIC_URL = '/signup/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `URL patterns`

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work, same error. I'm using django 3.0.3 if that helps